# How to get the occurrence of the number from array?

Tags: javascript

### Here is the what I going to do.

I have an array of numbers. I want to get the occurrence of the numbers and I want to add every occurrence number of the number to 1000,2000,3000 ......etc except 1s value

```
EX: let testArray = [{0:250},{1:150},{2:250},{3:250}]

I want to get make this value something like this [250,150,1250,2250]
```

but  my code go through the whole array and find the occurrence and numerically add the 1000, I don't want to go through the whole array. I just want to do

- go to 1 to first occurrence value and return same value (250)
- then come back and go to second occurrence and return 250 + 1000 = 1250
- then come back and go to third occurrence and return 250 + 2000 = 2250

**here is the code I try to do**

```
arrayFunc(){
  let array =  [{0:250},{1:150},{2:250},{3:250}]

  array.forEach((ID,index)) => {

   let result = this.myFunc(array, index)

   console.log(result)

  }
}

myFunc(array, index){

  let count = 0
  let addingnumber = 1000
  
  for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
  
    if(array[i] === array[index] && i <= index){
    
      count++
    }
  }

  if(count >= 2){

     let result = (addingnumber* (count-1)) + array[index]
     return result 
   }
     return array[index]
}
```

- above code process is firstly in **arrayFunc** function give the full
  array and **index number** of the first value to **myFunc**
- then **myFunc** get both data and go through all the array and get
  occurrence of the number
- then numerically add the 1000 value for array number multiplying
  occurrence number

Have any way to do this without going through whole array?

Comment: What is the actual array? What's shown isn't valid JS. Do you have an array of objects?

Comment: `testArray = [0:250,1:150,2:250,3:250]` isn't valid JS

Comment: I have edited please have a look

Comment: think there is no way to do something over an array without going through whole array. The best scenario is get your solution with only one iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object for counting the occurences of the value and add the count with a factor of 1000 to the value.

```js
const
    values = [250, 150, 250, 250],
    result = values.map((count => value => {
        count[value] ??= 0;
        return 1000 * count[value]++ + value;
    })({}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This exactly output, I want to this kind of process - > in the array. go to first value return it (250) go to second value return it (150) go to third value that time it want to identify i met this number before so i want to add 1000 for that then return ....something like that

Comment: whar do you need, actually?

Comment: please check this answer, I think is exactly what you are asking for.  You only need to copy that code without const work and skiping the last line, and go to browser console and run it, I did that, even you can modify values and test several times to check output of differents scenarios

Comment: Thanks for your answer I got the idea